# WP All-in-One Migration shows "wp-config already exists"

Tags: wordpress, plugins, development-environment

I have a Wordpress-Site in a local environment (Local by Flywheel). For getting it online I used a famous plugin called "WP All-in-One Migration". For that I have made a fresh WP installation on the domain to which I want to import the page. After importing the file all site work well except the homepage. It shows the message:

"The file wp-config.php already exists. If you need to reset any of the configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try installing now."

I am using Google Chrome and no caching plugins in wordpress. The error occurs in other browsers as well. What can I do?

- Deleted the browser cache
- Reloaded the page with developer tools without cache

Comment: Have you reset permalinks yet? (Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes). All-In-One has a habit of confusing where things WERE with where things ARE, and this often solves the problem for me.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks a lot! That solved the problem :D